# Change default Add File path in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

When adding a new item in a Visual C++ project, the default path for the new file is the project path. Are there any per-project or per-solution settings that allow this default path to be modified?

For example, to add new files by default to a subdirectory of the project folder, or even to somewhere outside the project folder?

I understand that filters can be used to automatically organize files visually within the Solution Explorer based on file extension, but I would like to actually place the physical file in another location without the need to browse to it.

I'm using a Visual C++ project as a container to to manage and organize (filter) editing of runtime-compiled files, and don't want developers to accidentally place new files outside of the intended folder, nor do I want the project file to exist in this code folder.

I did discover that if you create a new file in a sub directory of the project, that the Add Item dialog will default to that path when you add another file during that session, but it does not persist the default to the project or solution for future sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built-in.  Some commercial add ins make the behavior better. For example, [Whole Tomato's Visual Assist X package](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp) always uses the same directory as the currently open file, IIRC.

There are a couple of open source add ins that let you modify the behavior. For example, [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2010/05/18/vsnewfile-a-visual-studio-addin-to-more-easily-add-new-items-to-a-project.aspx).